# Order numbers in c++ and recognize the repeated ones

Tags: c++

I was trying to make a program in c++ that should order 3 random numbers (the user will write them) and then print which is the higher and the lower, but if two numbers or more are equal should print it.

**New code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;

    cout << "num1" << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "num2" << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    cout << "num3" << endl;
    cin >> num3;

    if(num1 == num2 && num3==num2 && num1==num3){
        cout << "all numbers are equal";
    }
    else if (num1 == num2){
        cout << "num1 and num2 are equal";
    }

    else if (num2 == num3){
        cout << "num2 and num3 are equal";
    }

    else if(num3 == num1){
        cout << "num1 and num3 are equal";
    }

    else{
    if (num1 != num2 && num2 != num3 && num3 != num1){
        if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3){
            cout << "higher is num1";
        }

        else if(num2 > num1 && num2 > num3){
            cout << "higher is num2";
        }
        else if(num3 > num1 && num3 > num2){
            cout << "higher is num3";
        }
    }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**New problem:**
The programm needs to know which is the lowest too, so how can I do that?

***Old code:***

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;

    cout << "num1" << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "num2" << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    cout << "num3" << endl;
    cin >> num3;

    if(num1 == num2 && num3==num2 && num1==num3){
        cout << "all your numbers are equal";
    }

    if (num1 != num2 && num2 != num3 && num3 != num1){
        if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3){
            cout << "num1";
        }

        else if(num2 > num1 && num2 > num3){
            cout << "num2";
        }
        else /*(num3 > num1 && num3 > num2)*/{//Here I tried to use and else if
            cout << "num3";
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

***Old problem***
This code is all wrong, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please help me.
And I have a last question, do I have a limit of if's into a if sentence? or I just can't write two else if or..? Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with the code? Are you getting the wrong output? I notice that you are missing a `{` after you `else` statement.

Comment: You know there is a boolean compound operator *besides* `&&`, right ?

Comment: So what happens if `num1 == num2` but they are different than `num3`? Should you maybe handle that case? [edited the tags: this has little to do with randomness or numbers (that is, it does not have anything more to do with numbers than any other program) or ordering (you are not ordering anything, just finding the max]

Comment: @GWW the `{` isn't missing, look carefully between the two comments

Comment: The nice thing about C++ is that is has so many nice [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) in the standard library. Like [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) to sort a [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). Or perhaps [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) and [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) which might be useful too?

Comment: Well, it seems that I figured out the problem I just wrote an else, if(num1 == num2 && num3==num2 && num1==num3){...} else {...}, and then I wrote more code that can know which numbers are equal, but I need to know which is the lowest and then I just got blocked, I don't know how to do that... I will edit my code, so you can know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::set<int> numbers;
    int input;

    for (int i=1; i<=3; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Enter number " << i << ": ";
        std::cin >> input;
        numbers.insert(input);
    }

    if (numbers.size() < 3) {
        std::cout << "You entered the same number more than once, silly!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Nevertheless, ";
    }

    std::cout << "the maximum number is " << *numbers.rbegin() << std::endl;
}
```

The important feature of this code is that it takes advantage of the properties of `std::set` which are:

1. It keeps all its elements in sorted order
2. It does not allow duplicate elements

`std::set::rbegin` is used to get the last element, which is the largest number (because the numbers are automatically sorted).

This code does not display which numbers are the largest and smallest, but this can easily be added. For example, `std::set::insert` returns information that can allow you to determine which insertion failed in the set. An std::set can contain only single copies of its contained objects.  Therefore, if the user enters a number more than once the calls to insert will fail.

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code solves your purpose. It has three functions `findLargest`, `findSmallest` and `checkEqual`. This is a very basic program and can be modified to your needs on how to display and what to return etc etc.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void findLargest(int n1,int n2,int n3)
{
    if(n1>n2 && n1>n3)
    {
        cout<<"Largest number is :"<<n1;
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    else if((n2>n1) && (n2>n3))
    {
        cout<<"Largest number is :"<<n2;
        cout<<"\n";
    }

    else
    {
        cout<<"Largest number is :"<<n3;
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}

void findSmallest(int n1,int n2,int n3)
{
    if(n1<=n2 && n1<=n3)
    {
        cout<<"Smallest number is :"<<n1;
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    else if((n2<=n1) && (n2<=n3))
    {
        cout<<"Smallest number is :"<<n2;
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Smallest number is :"<<n3;
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
int checkEqual(int n1,int n2,int n3)
{
    if(n1==n2 && n2==n3 && n3==n1)
    {
        cout<<"All three are equal";
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    else if(n1==n2||n2==n3||n3==n1)
    {
        cout<<"Two numbers are equal";
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"None are equal.. Finding Largest and Smallest....!!";
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
int main() {

    int num1,num2,num3;
    cout<<"Enter the numbers";
    cin>>num1>>num2>>num3;
    cout<<"\n";
    checkEqual(num1,num2,num3);
    findSmallest(num1,num2,num3);
    findLargest(num1,num2,num3);
    return 0;
}
```

**Ideone link**: http://ideone.com/hz4keQ

Hope it helps. :)